# Running an .exe's main(), as part of a .dll

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have an application that relies on .dlls to extend functionality (modules).
I would like to embed some specific functionality from another program (which is a server).

The other program has a relatively simple `n-main.cpp`

```
#include <n.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
     // creates a listen server and blocks the main thread
     // until it receives SIGKILL/SIGTERM or a custom HTTP header to stop 
     n::start(argc,argv); 
}
```

So I did this:

```
#include <modulespecs.h>
#include <mymodule.h> // only some general specs
#include <n.h> // copied from n-main.cpp, no errors

// The main program calls this function to attach the module
void onModuleAttached(){

     // create some fake arguments
     int argc = 2;
     char * argv[] = {"n.exe","someconfig.js"}; 

     // and act as if 
     n::start(argc,argv);
}
```

This works perfect so far, the server is created, waits for incoming connections, and answers requests properly.

The only problem is that when the module is loaded, the server blocks the main application, so the main app doesn't continue running because it waits for the server in my module to end activity first (which doesn't happen). And even if it did, the server has logic to close the main application completely when dying.

Things I tried:

```
  #include <thread>

  void create_server(){
      int argc = 2;
      char * argv[] = {"n.exe","someconfig.js"}; 

      // and act as if 
      n::start(argc,argv);
  }
  void onModuleAttached(){

      // crashes
      std::thread test(create_server); 

      // creates the server, then exits immediately
      std::thread (create_server).join();

      // same as join()
      std::thread (create_server).detach();
  }
```

Is there a specific way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're calling `onModuleLoaded()` from your `DllMain()` function.  `DllMain()` gets called while the OS loader lock is held, and so you should [never do anything scary inside `DllMain()`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/28/63880.aspx).  Creating threads is one such scary thing, so you should never do that inside `DllMain()`.

The recommended way of avoiding this is to have a separate DLL entry point which does the scary stuff, and **document** your DLL such that that entry point must be called after DLL initialization.  Also provide a corresponding exit routine to be called before unloading the DLL.

For example:

```
DLLEXPORT BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    // Nothing much here
}

std::thread server_thread;

DLLEXPORT void StartServer()
{
    server_thread = std::thread(create_server);
}

DLLEXPORT void StopServer()
{
    server_thread.join();
}
```

Then your main program can look like this:

```
// Load the DLL and get its entry and exit routines
HMODULE serverDLL = LoadLibrary(...);
void (*StartServer)() = (void (*)())GetProcAddress(serverDLL, "StartServer");
void (*StopServer)() = (void (*)())GetProcAddress(serverDLL, "StopServer");

// Call the entry routine to start the server on a new thread
StartServer();

// Do other main program stuff
// ...

// We're done now, tell the server to stop
StopServer();
FreeLibrary(serverDLL);
```

Comment: This already happens. Except `StartServer()` and `StopServer()` are called for every module (including mine), and they're actually called `onModuleAttached()` and `onModuleDetached()`. Trying this approach with `std::thread` declared outside of functions results in the main app exiting. Sadly.

Comment: I tried to generalize the question to abide by the rules. Your answer was correct in the given situation, I had to change my approach anyway. Thank you.